# srcset and custom field get_post_meta and wp_get_attachment_url

Tags: functions, images, responsive

I would like to use the new wordpress 4.4 function srcset with an image which comes from a custom-field like this

```
  <img src="<?php $bigimg = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'bg_file', true); echo wp_get_attachment_url( $bigimg );?>" alt="">
```

How could I get the srcset function work with it?

```
wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( 380, 'medium' );
```

srcset is already activated for post_thumbnails in my functions.php.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put two and two together:

```
<img src="<?php $bigimg = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'bg_file', true ); echo wp_get_attachment_url( $bigimg ); ?>" srcset="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $bgimg, 'medium' ) ?>"  alt="" />
```